# What is a proper way to create a secure login procedure?

Tags: php, html, security, session, cookies

I would like to know what would be a proper way to create a login procedure.

Up to this point I thought it would be a good way to create a `$_SESSION['login']` and even a `$_COOKIE['login']` that both have the same content which is a kind of a timestamp plus an encrypted form of the password.

The logic behind that idea is to check if both exist and to compare their contents. If both exist and is the content equal you get access to the protected pages.

I do know that a Cookie is a kind of a Session. A Cookie will be stored on the users client site and the a Session as well but will last only as long as the browser will be open. I thought it would be possible to extend the lifetime of a Session even when the browser will be closed and the Session destroyed.

This should ensure that the SESSION could not be hacked and the COOKIE be stolen what makes it impossible for a hacker to get access to a profile of an User.

Am I right with that thoughts or how do you people did it?

Thanks alot.

Comment: Do you understand how sessions and session hijacking works? If so, why is storing an additional cookie more secure then? (Tip: it's not.)

Comment: hi, no I dont know how it works. I just know that it is possible. I also know that a Session is a kind of Cookie but not accessable, i thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off you need to understand the difference between sessions and cookies.

Sessions and cookies are both key=>value stores. But *where* they're stored has great impact on their security properties.

Cookies are stored on the client machine. They are *unsafe*. A user can modify the value of a cookie, forget a cookie, send more cookies etc. Cookies can be stored for a very long period of time (months, years). Since the client stores the cookie you don't need to worry too much about space constraints. Just keep in mind that all the cookies are sent with every request.

Things you store in cookies are typically fairly inconsequential things like some preference settings or "I've already seen your popup asking me about questionnaire".

Session data is stored on the server, only the server can read from it and write to it. The user never sees what is in the session. Session data typically expires quickly, let's say anywhere between 30 minutes and 24 hours.

But how do you know which session belongs to which visitor? Well, you use a session identifier cookie. **This is the only cookie you need** for authentication. In PHP this cookie is `PHPSESSID` and it's created and used automatically when you call `session_start();`. The session cookie is a cookie with a random value that is hard to 'guess', which makes it secure.

The user will keep the session cookie. You can find the associated session data (automatically using `$_SESSION`). In the session data you can store whether the user is logged in, if so as which user, you can even store the rights a user has (like a mini-cache). You can treat this as an untamperable key=>value store, just make sure not to store too much in there (the limits depend on the storage mechanism).

Sessions are stored in a specific place; where depends on your webserver and OS. In PHP you can specify your own session storage handler by calling [`session_set_save_handler`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php). This allows you to, for instance, keep your session data in a database.

If the value of the session identifier cookie is somehow exposed an attacker can *hijack* the session. It can be exposed by using an unsecured connection on a wifi access point (like in a bar). To counter this use HTTPS; cookies sent over HTTPS are encrypted and safe from this kind of man-in-the-middle attack. This is what the [Firesheep](http://www.pcworld.com/article/209333/how_to_hijack_facebook_using_firesheep.html) plugin did (in 2010)

Comment: hello and thanks. what i did not understood is how to check the value. how can i compare that the value of the server session will be the same as in the client site ones because i have no table where i can read it out?

Comment: If you call `session_start();` PHP will automatically find the session for that visitor (using the `PHPSESSID` cookie - if there is no `PHPSESSID` cookie you will get a new empty session). You can fetch and create the session manually but you don't need to. After calling `session_start();` the session global `$_SESSION` is available. You can check and set the value of the session identifier with `session_id()`

Comment: something like if '($_COOKIE['xy'] === "1")' would be something like if '($_SESSION === session_id())' right?

Comment: No. It would be `$_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"] === session_id()` but that is a moot statement because it should just be true.